# Can I change the 'no data' text to static number in Google data studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I am calculating the NPS score using the formulas

```
(COUNT(CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(How likely are you to recommend this training ?, "(9|10)") THEN How likely are you to recommend this training?
  ELSE NULL
END) / (COUNT(How likely are you to recommend this training?) / 100))  - (COUNT(Detractors) / (COUNT(How likely are you to recommend this training ?) / 100))
```

and it is working fine, however I have scores in the data for which the year, month and some other fields are not available , so when I click on the filter it display 'no data' text as it doesn't find the NPS rating for that filter value. What I want to do is to display a static number instead of 'no data' text for example 70.

```
COALESCE(
  (COUNT(CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(How likely are you to recommend this training?, "(9|10)") THEN How likely are you to recommend this training?
    ELSE NULL
  END) / (COUNT(How likely are you to recommend this training?) / 100))  - (COUNT(Detractors) / (COUNT(How likely are you to recommend this training?) / 100)),
  70
)
```

But it throws an error

```
Sorry, calculated fields can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and dimensions (non-aggregated values). Please check the aggregation types of the fields used in this formula. Learn more.
```

Any help?